# Move internet connection to a different floor

Tags: networking, router, dsl, wired

I want to migrate my internet to the second floor of my house, where i will have two PCs, leaving none at the ground floor. I already have a cat5 cable (just one) going from this floor to the second one, and just the router/modem from my ISP(DSL).

Im just not sure if i need a bridge or a switch, or another router.

Comment: Do you intend to move the modem upstairs as well? Do you have a phone jack where you intend to move it for your DSL connection? If so, it’s as simple as moving the modem upstairs and plugging everything in. Plug your computers in to the modem.

Comment: There is no jack upstairs, so i think i would have to leave the modem downstairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your router upstairs with the two computers, then all you need is connect two ethernet cables, one for each computer. Run the cables from the back of the modem to the ethenet socket in each of the computers.
Hope this helps and I hope I'm understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the router/modem on the ground floor & already have a single cable running to the new location, then to achieve your requirements with no further inter-floor wiring, add an unmanaged switch [ethernet 'hub', 1000 Base-T, $£€ 50 or so] at the end of your link cable & spur everything else from that.

Unless you are running some very serious in-house data transmission, that will be unlikely to be any slower than having the router moved up to the 2nd floor.

Comment: Would the two PCs be sharing the same connection that way? Is there any downside?

Comment: The difference between plugging 2 machines into 2 sockets on the same router vs via a switch is negligible. To the network, it is very slightly different. To the user it may as well be identical. There is no appreciable downside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CAT5 from the round floor to the second floor to carry the telephone signal from the ground floor wall jack to the router on the second floor. CAT5 makes excellent POTS phone cable and will not attenuate the DSL signal significantly. Just choose one pair in the CAT5 cable ([Blue/Blue-White, Green/Green-White, Orange/Orange-White, or Brown-Brown-White](https://www.ertyu.org/steven_nikkel/ethernetcables.html)) and [attach it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4hAJM9xmqI) [another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHuztiLa0Tc) to the center contacts of an [RJ-11 jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ11,_RJ14,_RJ25_wiring), then plug the CAT5 with the RJ-11 plugs that into the phone jack downstairs, and the DSL modem upstairs. Do *not* use extension cords.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the modem where it is, you just have to connect the cable that goes to the second floor to the modem and to the router. You'd only need to buy another router if you notice a drop in speed in wifi on the first floor, since the router will be on the second floor.